# log4net: stacktrace and stacktracedetails logging always

Tags: log4net

I have an ADO.Net appender with the two parameter:

```
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@stacktrace" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%stacktrace{4}" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@stacktracedetail" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%stacktracedetail{5}" /> 
  </layout>
</parameter>
```

Edit: The code above works now fine.

> > Eg %stacktrace{4} would show you the top four functions of the stack trace.

See also documentaton:
https://logging.apache.org/log4net/log4net-1.2.13/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but you say that your goal is to `get the stacktrace and stacktracedetail only for specific log levels` . which sounds like you only want stacktrace for debug messages, but the stack trace level specifier does not specific **if** logging is to take place, but specifies how deep the stack trace goes. Eg %stacktrace{4} would show you the top four functions of the stack trace.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I misunderstood the documentation. 
>> Eg %stacktrace{4} would show you the top four functions of the stack trace.